# Get everything for each user where its login date is the latest

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying for too long to figure out how to write a mysql query to retrieve everything from a user, for each user, where its login date is the latest. It should work as the following:

```
+----+------+------------+---------+---------+
| ID | Name |    Date    | ColumnA | ColumnB |
+----+------+------------+---------+---------+
|  1 | John | 10/12/2019 |    x    |    x    |
|  2 | John | 08/12/2019 |    x    |    x    |
|  3 | Jane | 07/12/2019 |    x    |    x    |
|  4 | John | 03/12/2019 |    x    |    x    |
|  5 | Jane | 01/12/2019 |    x    |    x    |
+----+------+------------+---------+---------+
```

The desired output would be

```
+----+------+------------+---------+---------+
| ID | Name |    Date    | ColumnA | ColumnB |
+----+------+------------+---------+---------+
|  1 | John | 10/12/2019 |    x    |    x    |
|  3 | Jane | 07/12/2019 |    x    |    x    |
+----+------+------------+---------+---------+
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this with a single query? It seems to be simple, and probably it is, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Store dates as dates, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What MySQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is to use a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

If `date` can be repeated, then the above will return multiple rows for a given user.  In that case, use the unique `id` instead, in this way:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name
              order by t2.date desc  -- might want "id desc" or "id asc" here as well
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: 890k? You're going to run out of digits soon.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Jon Skeet got there long before I ever will.  And StackOverflow did have to fix a bug to prepare for seven digit reputations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case for **Scalar-Aggregate Comparison**, which will allow you to select correlated data from aggregates without the need for a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(Date) AS Date,
    SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(Date, ColumnA)), 11) AS ColumnA,
    SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(Date, ColumnB)), 11) AS ColumnB
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name;
```

One note is that you'll want to ensure that `CONCAT(Date, ColumnA)` formats the date in ISO-8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) so that it maintains alphabetical ordinality.

If not, you may need to add a `DATE_FORMAT` to the query:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(Date) AS Date,
    SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'), ColumnA)), 11) AS ColumnA,
    SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'), ColumnB)), 11) AS ColumnB
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name;
```

You can read more about the technique here: https://www.stevenmoseley.com/high-performance-correlated-aggregate-sql-queries-without-ctes